# Error returned when harvesting from GeoNetwork instance – bad-xml-response

Tags: geonetwork, csw

I’m attempting to harvest metadata records from a target GeoNetwork (v3.10.0.0) instance and am receiving a “Harvest error bad-xml-response” with the following returned response:

[image: UI error response]

Please see [full response file here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13W3D7x3diovOPGdACW7pKiUC-y39FL-OF6Uc0STjGEo/edit?usp=sharing).

Target Env:   Deployed from .war file running on Tomcat 9 and CentOS 7.

The CSW test calls (csw-GetCapabilities, csw-DescribeRecord, csw-GetRecords) from within the target instance UI seem to work ok, but not sure if they actually use the external URL Get interface or if they just exercise the GeoNetwork library calls internally.

We have other harvesters set up and are harvesting records from similar(but not same) instances just fine.  There have been some minor customizations done to the landing page of the target instance (noted in yellow highlight in the full response file), but I don’t understand how/why that would affect the harvest request.

Comment: that is returning the main GeoNetwork - are you sure the target endpoint is set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's a misconfiguration on the part of the server.

```
http://servir-data.ciat.cgiar.org/srv/eng/csw?service=CSW&request=GetCapabilities
```

gives results as do other requests to the HTTP version of the URL, like say:

```
http://servir-data.ciat.cgiar.org/srv/eng/csw?service=CSW&request=GetDomain&version=2.0.2&propertyname=title

<csw:GetDomainResponse xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2">
    <csw:DomainValues type="csw:Record">
    <csw:PropertyName>title</csw:PropertyName>
    <csw:ListOfValues>
        <csw:Value>A new high‐resolution nationwide aboveground carbon map for Brazil</csw:Value>
        <csw:Value>Deforestation and Wildfire Risk</csw:Value>
        <csw:Value>Global Wetlands</csw:Value>
        <csw:Value>Progression of forest loss in the Madre de Dios region, Peru (2013-2018)</csw:Value>
        <csw:Value>Spatial and temporal contrasts in the distribution of crops and pastures across Amazonia: A new agricultural land use data set from census data since 1950</csw:Value>
        <csw:Value>Sustentabilidade em debate 5 - Números detalhados do novo código florestal e suas implicações para os PRAs</csw:Value>
        <csw:Value>Western Amazon Fire Forecast</csw:Value>
        <csw:Value>Who owns Brazilian lands?</csw:Value>
    </csw:ListOfValues>
    </csw:DomainValues>
</csw:GetDomainResponse>
```

But if you look at the GetCapabilities response you'll see that it says requests should go to:

```
https://servir-data.ciat.cgiar.org:8443/srv/eng/csw
```

and requests to that location don't work.

I see that requests to the standard https port work too like:

```
https://servir-data.ciat.cgiar.org/srv/eng/csw?service=CSW&request=GetDomain&version=2.0.2&propertyname=identifier
```

So the misconfiguration is the specification of **port 8443**

If your harvester honours information it parses from the GetCapabilities response, your harvesting won't work

Comment: Someone needs to set the server proxy setting.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, we temporarily opened up port 8443 (the NAT tables take care of the forwarding from 443 to 8443), and we are also testing with HTTP.  But we are still getting the error.  At this point, an IT colleague has opened another ticket with more log file informatio0n from both servers. Please see: [GeoNetwork Harvesting gives error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381019/geonetwork-harvesting-gives-error)

I will close this ticket in deference to that other ticket.